# Refreshing or making renderUI reactive

Tags: shiny

I use observe to create png files from a simulation and then display the png files using renderUI as a slider animation. Now this done for various sample sizes and the png file names include the sample size - e.g. RplotSS2step1.png ... RplotSS2step20.png for sample size of 2. All works fine the first time that sample size is chosen but when the same sample size is later re-chosen new png files are created (different simulation) but the old png files (that no longer exist in the image directory) are just re-shown.

Is there a way to get renderUI to "reimage" when the same file names are repeatedly used. If I add a random tag to the file names to always make them unique I would have to automatically erase them which seems risky.

```
Nimgurl <- reactive({
  i=input$Nmyslider
  samplesize=input$num
  return(paste0("./images/RplotSS",samplesize,"step",i,".png"))
 })
output$Nui <- renderUI({
  tags$div(
     tags$img(src = Nimgurl())
   )
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best solution. I solved with `renderImage` and using a dinamic alternative text.

```
 output$image<-   renderImage({

                            # Return a list containing the filename
                                    list(src = Nimgurl(),
                                     contentType = 'image/png',
                                     alt = ndg())
                                  }, deleteFile = T)
```

where `ndg()` have to be a reactive input (it could be a random number as you say).

Then in ui.r you can use:

```
div(imageOutput("roi"))
```